# Very sloe FPS on IceCream Sandiwch but Perfect on previous version

Tags: android, andengine

I am using AndEngine 1 and developed an app which is running on 55+Fps but when I ran it on IceCreamSandwich it becomes too slow now the FPS is <5.
Can any one help me with this what could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using DDMS to [profile your application](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesother/248-using-ddms-to-profile-android-apps) and see which calls are taking the most time in each frame. That way you'll be able to tell what the actual problem is instead of guessing at it.